# find all id where deleted column value should be 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

i have to find all the records from a table in my mvc controller where the deleted column values == 0 
table person

```
personId int,
personName varchar(50),
deletd bit

var ids = db.Persons.OrderBy(p => p.personId).Where(p => p.personId > 2 && p.deleted == 0 ).All;
```

please suggest how to achieve that.

Comment: What is the problem? Explain more...

Comment: i have to find out all the PersonId whose deleted column value is 0

like this sql query select personid from Person where Deleted = 0

Comment: `.All()` returns a `bool` value, not any actual records. `.All()` checks see if a specified condition evaluates to true or false. See  documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query you should use:

```
var ids = db.Persons.Where(p => p.personId > 2 && p.deleted == 0 )
                    .OrderBy(p => p.personId)
                    .Select(p => p.personId);
```

Here you are doing the query in the WHERE clause. I'm using the `personId > 2` because you use it in you question...

Then, if you need it sorted in some way... you use the OrderBy clause.

So far... you have a list of Persons...

Then you select the "column" you need... and there is the select.

Your "`ids`" will be a collection of ints.

Till here you didn't hit the database... if you add a "`.ToList()`" at the end, you will retrieve the data from the database. If you don't do this, you code will work anyway... and automagically when needed it will retrive the data.

Comment: `Where` filters the records that come back (here only asking for those records where `personId` is greater than 2 and `deleted` is 0. `OrderBy` just orders the result set by `personId`. `Select` here projects the fields that are returned, here being only the `personId` values. If you want all of the fields to come back, just leave that `Select` off.

Comment: have to display the records based on these id when i increment the id like persons++. persons is the parameter of the action method. is it possible or how can i do that please help. i am getting error when deleted == 1

Comment: @Miranda, update your answer, adding the code you mention. It is at least hard to understand what you need. About your "error" you need to tell as what the error says at least... we are glad to help, but far from mind readers. ;)

Comment: `public ActionResult Next(int personid) { var ids = db.Persons.Where(p => p.personId > 2 && p.deleted == 0 ).OrderBy(p => p.personId).Select(p => p.personId); personid++; if (ids.Contains(personid))
                {
                    viewTeamList.ViewTeamDetails(personid);
                    return PartialView("_ViewTeamDetails", viewTeamList);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", viewTeamList);
                }`

Comment: may i update my question based on this requirement, i am accepting your answer based on my previous requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Thanks anyways!

```
public ActionResult errandPreview()
        {
            var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            //var errand = DB.errandList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == userID);
            var errand = DB.errandList.Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTimePosted).FirstOrDefault();
            var model = new errands
            {
                Title = errand.Title
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```